# Handling an XML file with Ruby and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, rubygems, nokogiri

I am new to programming so bear with me. I have many XML documents that look like this:

File name: PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_10094.xml.gz

```
<ExperimentCollection version="2.1">
<Experiment>
    <ExperimentAccession>1015</ExperimentAccession>
    <Title>Protein complexes in Saccharomyces cerevisiae (GPM06600002310)</Title>
    <ShortLabel>GPM06600002310</ShortLabel>
    <Protocol>
        <ProtocolName>None</ProtocolName>
    </Protocol>
    <mzData version="1.05" accessionNumber="1015">
        <cvLookup cvLabel="RESID" fullName="RESID Database of Protein Modifications" version="0.0" address="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/RESID/" />
        <cvLookup cvLabel="UNIMOD" fullName="UNIMOD Protein Modifications for Mass Spectrometry" version="0.0" address="http://www.unimod.org/" />
        <description>
            <admin>
                <sampleName>GPM06600002310</sampleName>
                <sampleDescription comment="Ho, Y., et al., Systematic identification of protein complexes in Saccharomyces cerevisiae by mass spectrometry. Nature. 2002 Jan 10;415(6868):180-3.">
                    <cvParam cvLabel="NEWT" accession="4932" name="Saccharomyces cerevisiae (Baker's yeast)" value="Saccharomyces cerevisiae" />
                </sampleDescription>
                            </admin>
        </description>
        <spectrumList count="0" />
    </mzData>
        </Experiment>
```

I want to take out the text in between "Title", "ProtocolName", and "SampleName" and save into a text file that has the same name as the .xml.gz. I have the following code so far (based on posts I saw on this site), but it seems not to work:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_10094.xml.gz"))
@ExperimentCollection = doc.css("ExperimentCollection Title").map {|node| node.children.text }
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: as regards the 'please delete for me' comments you left in place of your question (prior to my rolling it back to a question), you can delete your own questions by using the links below your question text (you should see something like: `edit | close | delete`) if you want to delete it you're free to do so, since **you** own the question. I rolled it back because it seems legitimate, and deserving of answers. If you've solved your problem already, please post your solution. Otherwise, give it time for people to see it, and offer their help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are happy with REXML, AND there's only one `<Experiment>` per file, then something like the following should help ... (by the way, above text is invalid XML since no closing `<ExperimentCollection>` tag)

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML
xml=<<EOD
<Experiment>
    <ExperimentAccession>1015</ExperimentAccession>
    <Title>Protein complexes in Saccharomyces cerevisiae (GPM06600002310)</Title>
    <ShortLabel>GPM06600002310</ShortLabel>
    <Protocol>
        <ProtocolName>None</ProtocolName>
    </Protocol>
    <mzData version="1.05" accessionNumber="1015">
        <cvLookup cvLabel="RESID" fullName="RESID Database of Protein Modifications" version="0.0" address="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/RESID/" />
        <cvLookup cvLabel="UNIMOD" fullName="UNIMOD Protein Modifications for Mass Spectrometry" version="0.0" address="http://www.unimod.org/" />
        <description>
            <admin>
                <sampleName>GPM06600002310</sampleName>
                <sampleDescription comment="Ho, Y., et al., Systematic identification of protein complexes in Saccharomyces cerevisiae by mass spectrometry. Nature. 2002 Jan 10;415(6868):180-3.">
                    <cvParam cvLabel="NEWT" accession="4932" name="Saccharomyces cerevisiae (Baker's yeast)" value="Saccharomyces cerevisiae" />
                </sampleDescription>
                            </admin>
        </description>
        <spectrumList count="0" />
    </mzData>
        </Experiment>
EOD

doc = Document.new xml
doc.elements["Experiment/Title"].text
doc.elements["Experiment/Protocol/ProtocolName"].text
doc.elements["Experiment/mzData/description/admin/sampleName"].text
```